# Spring Data Pageable breaking Spring Data JPA OrderBy

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple JpaRepository with a finder that returns records ordered by a property named "number" in descending order.  The "number" property is also the @Id of my entity.  This works just fine, however there's thousands of records, so I want to return a Page instead of a List.

```
@Repository
public interface ReceiptRepository extends JpaRepository<Receipt, BigDecimal> {

    @Query
    public List<Receipt> findByStorerOrderByNumberDesc(String storer);
}
```

If I change my finder to something like the following, the sorting no longer works.  I've tried using the sort capability of the Pageable argument, but it didn't work.  Also removed the OrderByNumberDesc, but same result.

```
@Repository
public interface ReceiptRepository extends JpaRepository<Receipt, BigDecimal> {

    @Query
    public Page<Receipt> findByStorerOrderByNumberDesc(String storer, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**EDIT - added controller method**

The following is my controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
public PagedResources<Receipt> receipts(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {
    Page<Receipt> receipts = receiptRepository.findByStorer("003845", pageable);
    return assembler.toResource(receipts, receiptResourceAssembler);
}
```

I feel I'm missing something very basic here.

I'm using Spring Data JPA 1.5.2 and Commons 1.7.2.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

Add the sort to your Pageable when you create it:

e.g.

```
Pageable pageable ...;
pageable.getSort().and(new Sort(Direction.ASC, "prop1", "prop1"));
```

or in Spring MVC you can do:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
public PagedResources<Receipt> receipts(@PageableDefaults(sort = { "x",
            "y", "z" }, value = 10)Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {
    Page<Receipt> receipts = receiptRepository.findByStorer("003845", pageable);
    return assembler.toResource(receipts, receiptResourceAssembler);
}
```

Comment: Although the answer is correct you could elaborate a little on why this is happening.

Comment: I should have specified this is a Spring MVC app and my Pageable is being injected into my controller method, so the Pageable is being populated from request parameters.  I've tried adding `&sort=number,desc` to my request, but still it doesn't sort that way.

Comment: Well you have a pageable so just do as above.

Comment: The query parameters come in as "?page=0&size=20&sort=number,desc", which is converted to a Pageable with page=0, size=20 and sort with descending order on the "number" property.  So I don't need to modify the Pageable, it already contains what I want.  The problem is that it isn't working.

Comment: What version of Spring Data and Spring Data commons are you using?

Comment: Spring Data JPA 1.5.2 and Commons 1.7.2.

Comment: It will only be working after you click a link to sort. The initial sort will be wrong unless you have specified a default or added a sort. See updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I've determined the problem isn't on the MVC side.  I wrote a unit test to query my repo and provided a PageRequest to the Pageable argument, but the data still doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: Just to add to this, I copied the generated query from my console output and ran it manually inside my IDE, the result came back sorted correctly.  So I don't know why from my app that it doesn't.

Comment: If your method is still called findByStorerOrderByNumberDesc() it would, regardless of what the Pageable is doing.

Comment: Paste the generated SQL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53824/discussion-between-patrick-grimard-and-alan-hay)

Comment: I think I solved my problem, oddly by specifying on my `EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter` that I was using Sybase instead of DB2.  I guess DB2400 more closely resembles Sybase than strict DB2.